# Opening files in python in vs code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I use this code in terminal to open files for python and it worked, but it doesn't work in vs code. It says:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Desktop/Untitled.txt'...

How should I change it for vs code?...
I don't know How vs code searches for files

```
f = open('Desktop/Untitled.txt')
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work in vs code" What happens when you run the code in VS Code? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path?

Comment: I tried this too but the error occurred again  f = open('Macintosh HD/Users/.../Desktop/Untitled.txt')

Comment: What I found is that if the file is in the same folder as th py file i can use this and that would be no problem:
f = open('Untitled.txt')

Comment: I suggest you read about file paths. Learn about the difference between an absolute path and a relative path. You should also learn about the so-called "current working directory" and how you can leverage it to use relative paths to your files.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the absolute path to the file.

```
f = open('C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Untitled.txt')
```

Comment: It is on mac and i did but the error occurred again

Comment: Try `f = open(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Untitled.txt'))`.